# Cancellation Token not working for azure queue trigger function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, cancellation-token

I am trying to implement one azure queue trigger function with CancellationToken registration so that I can get updated data when the function app restarts or get stops.

I Refer to [Cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?view=azure-cli-latestefbc89&tabs=v2%2Ccmd#cancellation-tokens) doc and tried in my function but it's not triggering when the function app stop or restart while it's working fine for the HTTP trigger function but not working for the Queue trigger function when I restart or stop function app.
Here is my sample code of the Queue trigger function

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
{
    token.Register(() =>
    {
        log.LogError("Function app is stopping");
    });
    log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            log.LogError("Function was cancelled at iteration {0}", i);
            break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        log.LogInformation("Normal processing for queue message={0}", myQueueItem);
    }
    log.LogInformation($"Completed");
}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here or it's like this only?.

Ideally, it should be working for all types of functions, right? Also is there any way I can get the reason for the function app restart or stop?

Comment: Is this in-proc or out-of-process ? your method is lacking the `Function` or `FunctionName` attribute.

Comment: It is in the process only. It's working fine without `FunctionName` attribute.

Comment: You can refer to open GitHub issues: [Allow a function to handle execution timeout gracefully and prevent process restart](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2153) and [Question about CancellationToken's](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6195) You can also open an issue: [Azure/azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues)